# How to pass a variable in the query below

Tags: c#, linq

I have linq request.
I need get `item.Title` in select. how do this?

```
var list = (from item in answer.SubItems.OfType<TItemView>()
            where item.SubItems != null
            from ty in item.SubItems
            select ty as TDealRequestView
                into request
                select new
                {
                    itemTitle = item.Title,//item not visible 
                    Title = request.Title,

                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use keyword : let

```
in order to initialize your value request.Title

let request = your treatment... (request is local variable of your query)
```

Answer (score 1):

cannot check right now, but try:

```
String title;

var list = (from item in answer.SubItems.OfType<TItemView>()
        where item.SubItems != null
        let title=item.title 
        ...

        //now use title
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
select ty as TDealRequestView
            into request
```

with:

```
let request = ty as TDealRequestView
```